# Diferencia de ordenamiento entre postgres y mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Me acaba de surgir una duda y me gustaría que alguien me pudiese explicar el por qué.

Lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un comparativo de una consulta entre PostgreSQL y MySQL. Aplico la clausula order by en ambas consultas y orden de el resultado varía.

Supongo que puede ser por el tipo de encoding que esta configurado para uno y otro.

Alguien me podría decir el por qué?

Aquí un ejemplo de la consulta empleada en ambos gestores:

```
SELECT
  a.nom_geo, b.termino_generico,
  b.jerarquia1, a.localidad, b.jerarquia1, a.localidad
FROM nmg16.publicacion a
LEFT JOIN nmg16.cat_ntng b ON a.cve_cla_tg = b.id_ntng
LEFT JOIN nmg16.cat_fuente fuente ON a.fuente = fuente.id_fuente
LEFT JOIN nmg16.cat_insumo insumo ON a.insumo_fte = CAST(insumo.id AS text)
ORDER BY b.jerarquia1 asc, a.nom_geo asc 
LIMIT 300
```

Comment: Sin datos de prueba, la salida que te esta generando, la salida esperada y demás información entonces poco podemos hacer, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Agrega datos para reproducir el caso y cuàl es el resultado esperado.